# Table NoWrap Option in iText 7?

Tags: itext, itext7

I'm converting iText5 code to iText7. One of the properties we use is NoWrap (= true) on some of our cells. What is the iText 7 equivolent? Thanks!

```
new PdfPCell { NoWrap = true, ... }
```

Comment: Please attach your iText 5 code and visual result of what you are trying to achieve, as well as what you have tried with iText 7 so far

Comment: The code is just new PdfPCell { NoWrap = true, ... }. Just looking for the equivalent of this property.

Comment: The effect, as the name implies, is that there's no wrapping if the size of the text/content would exceed the widths of the cell. It will just overflow past the bounds of the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Property.OVERFLOW_X` to control the overflow strategy of the content. But it needs to be set on the elements that contain the content, normally on a paragraph.

Here is an example of a code adding a table with a cell that contains content which does not fit in the given cell width (`100pt`):

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outFileName));

Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

Table table = new Table(new float[] {100, 100, 100});
table.setFixedLayout();
table.setWidth(300);
table.addCell("Hello world");
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("ThisIsAVeryLongLongWordWhichOverflowsCellWidth").setFontColor(ColorConstants.GREEN);
table.addCell(p);
p.setProperty(Property.OVERFLOW_X, OverflowPropertyValue.VISIBLE);
table.addCell("Last cell");
document.add(table);

document.close();
```

[image: result]